# Pass data from Views.py to Forms.py

Tags: python, django, forms, args, keyword-argument

I am trying to move data from my views.py to my forms.py pages. I am using the FormWizard, however i dont think it will matter here.

views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(CheckoutWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
    kwargs = super(CheckoutWizard, self).get_form_kwargs()

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CheckoutWizard, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'first_name': 'james'})
        kwargs.update({'last_name': 'bond'})
        form = CreditCardForm(kwargs)
        return kwargs
```

forms.py - in CreditCardForm

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    for a in args:
        for key in a:
            print("key: %s , value: %s" % (key, a[key]))

    super(CreditCardForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the forms file above I am accessing the data in *args with the nested loops because if i call args without the * i get this back

```
({'first_name': 'james', 'last_name': 'james'},)
```

which i believe is a tuple with a dictionary in it.

I have seen other solutions where other people are using **kwargs instead. My current solution feels a bit hacky so if there is a more correct or simpler way of doing this id appreciate the help. Its also strange to me that in views i am adding to kwargs, but then accessing that data in args. Any explanation on the differences would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CheckoutWizard, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'first_name': 'james'})
    kwargs.update({'last_name': 'bond'})
    # this will be called by cvb like form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
    # because you miss ** so you get your kwargs in arg
    # form = CreditCardForm(**kwargs)
    return kwargs


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    first_name = kwargs.pop('first_name')
    last_name= kwargs.pop('last_name')
    super(CreditCardForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: When i trade out my code with yours i get an error "KeyError" first_name